# Не могу получить список пользователей голосового канала discord

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Хочу получить список пользователей при старте бота (on_ready) для дискорда. Канал определяется верно (Проверял по названию и id), однако список пользователей не выводится.

```
import discord


class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_voice_state_update(self, member, before, after):
        if after.channel and after.channel != before.channel:
            print(f'Пользователь {member.name} защёл в {after.channel.name}')
        if before.channel and after.channel != before.channel:
            print(f'Пользователь {member.name} вышел из {before.channel.name}')

    async def on_ready(self):
        main_channel = client.get_channel(611541094747996183)
        members = main_channel.voice_channels[0].members
        print(members)


client = MyClient()

client.run('token')
```

У бота абсолютно все права и проставлены все галки на страницы управления им
[image: 1 страница прав][image: 2 страница прав][image: 3 cтраница прав]

[image: Галки самого бота]

Comment: А что выводится? Вообще ничего? Или пустой список?

Comment: @V-Mor, выводится []. Бот на моём сервере, в канале 3 человека. У бота абсолютно все права и проставлены все галки на страницы управления им

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Подробности насчёт прав и количества человек лучше внесите в вопрос, чтобы другие участники могли их сразу увидеть.

Comment: @V-Mor, исправил, может что-то ещё пойти не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему, связана была с тем, что в новой версии появились намерения.
Решается добавлением intents:

```
import discord
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
# или
# bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```

Источник: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html